# Unexpected Outcome in Playfair Cipher Program

Tags: c

**I'm having some trouble figuring out why I'm getting an unexpected outcome for the Digraphs in Row 4,5 and Column 4,5.**

For Example -

eg1) Plain Text Digraph  -> AR

Expected Outcome  -> RM

My outcome -> AM

eg2) Plain Text Digraph  -> AR

Expected Outcome  -> RM

My outcome -> AM

Basically , if the Digraph has characters from Second Last and Last Rows or Columns Respectively , The first half of the Digraph wont change.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main(){
    char str[30],key[30];

    strcpy(key, "Monarchy"); 
    printf("\nKey text: %s", key); 
    printf("\nPlain Text (CAPS ONLY): ");
    gets(str);

    printf("\n Key Matrix : ");    
    char keyM[5][5]={'M','O','N','A','R','C','H','Y','B','D','E','F','G','I','K','L','P','Q','S','T','U','V','W','X','Z'};

    printf("\n - - - - -\n");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%c  ",keyM[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf(" - - - - -");

    int pl = strlen(str);
    int CON=0;
    char pf[] = "Z";
    if(pl%2!=0)
    {
        strcat(str,pf);
        CON=1;
    }

    printf("\nAdjusted Text : %s \n - - - - - - \n",str);

    int lc=0;
    char Estr[30]="";
    for(int i=0;i<pl+CON;i++)
    {
        char tmpD1;
        char tmpD2;
        int D1r,D1c,D2r,D2c;

        tmpD1=str[i];
        tmpD2=str[i+1];
        i++;
        lc++;

        printf("Plain Diagraphs : %c %c \n",tmpD1,tmpD2);

        for(int Row=0;Row<5;Row++)
        {
            for(int Col=0;Col<5;Col++)
            {
                if(tmpD1==keyM[Row][Col])
                {
                    D1r=Row;
                    D1c=Col;
                }
                if(tmpD2==keyM[Row][Col])
                {
                    D2r=Row;
                    D2c=Col;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("Diagraph locations : %d %d and %d %d \n",D1r,D1c,D2r,D2c);

        int ConEx=0;
        int ConEy=0;
        if(D1c==D2c)
        {
            if(D1r+1>4)
            {
                D1r=0;
                ConEx=-1;
            }
            if(D2r+1>4)
            {
                D2r=0;
                ConEx=-1;
            }

            printf("USES CASE 1 ");
            printf("Encrypted Diagraphs : %c %c \n ---- \n",keyM[D1r+1+ConEx][D1c],keyM[D2r+1+ConEx][D2c]);
            strncat(Estr,&keyM[D1r+1+ConEx][D1c],1);
            strncat(Estr,&keyM[D2r+1+ConEx][D2c],1);

        }


        else if(D1r==D2r)
        {
            if(D1c+1>4)
            {
                D1c=0;
                ConEy=-1;
            }
            if(D2c+1>4)
            {
                D2c=0;
                ConEy=-1;
            }

            printf("USES CASE 2 ");
            printf("Encrypted Diagraphs : %c %c \n ---- \n",keyM[D1r][D1c+1+ConEy],keyM[D2r][D2c+1+ConEy]);
            strncat(Estr,&keyM[D1r][D1c+1+ConEy],1);
            strncat(Estr,&keyM[D2r][D2c+1+ConEy],1);
        }

        else if((D1r!=D2r)&&(D1c!=D2c))
        {
            printf("USES CASE 3 ");
            printf("Encrypted Diagraphs : %c %c \n ---- \n",keyM[D1r][D2c],keyM[D2r][D1c]);
            strncat(Estr,&keyM[D1r][D2c],1);
            strncat(Estr,&keyM[D2r][D1c],1);
        }

    }
    printf("Loop Counter : %d",lc);
    printf("\nCypher String : %s",Estr);


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here (at least for the given example, I did not check the other cases, there could be errors in them too)

```
        else if(D1r==D2r)
        {
            if(D1c+1>4)
            {
                D1c=0;
                ConEy=-1;
            }
            if(D2c+1>4)
            {
                D2c=0;
                ConEy=-1;
            }
```

You wrapping them around, but you do not increase them, but you should. This will fix it

```
        else if(D1r==D2r)
        {
            if(++D1c>4)
            {
                D1c=0;
                ConEy=-1;
            }
            if(++D2c>4)
            {
                D2c=0;
                ConEy=-1;
            }
```